# Finding a string inside all subdirectories

Tags: c++, directory, filesystems

I try to code a program that behaves like grep -r function. So far I can list all the subdirectories and folders inside of them recursively but what i need to do is to find a string inside all of these files and record them in a .log file. I am building with CMake on Ubuntu. The program compiles fine but probably I have something wrong with this function.(it basically saves the values found in a log file)

It's supposed to put inside the log file the following->
Directory:(line number):(the full line)

After the changes, the function works fine, I can see the directories and the line number of the searched word. The problem now is that I cannot see the line in the .log file, it shows in binary and not as a string. Do anyone know the reason ?

```
void showing_all_files(std::string path, std::string search)
{ 
      std::ofstream log_file; 
      log_file.open("grep_ex.log"); 
  
  
    for (const auto & entry : fs::recursive_directory_iterator(path))
        {   

            int line_no = 0; 
             string line; 
             ifstream infile(path); 

             while(getline(infile, line))
             {

                ++line_no; 
                auto pos = line.find(search); 
                if(pos != string::npos)
                    {
                        log_file << entry << ":" << line_no << ":" << line << endl; 
                    }

             }
           //  log_file << entry.path() << std::endl;

        }
        log_file.close(); 
}
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I don't know why when I execute the code, the log file doesn't fill up like in the previous subdirectories case where i could see all the files with their full path.

Comment: Did you already try to debug your program?

Comment: `ifstream infile(path);`  ->  `ifstream infile(entry.path());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ifstream infile(path);` Should be `ifstream infile(entry.path());`.

Comment: When I changed it, I got the following error this time. I use c++17 by the way.                                                       error: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_ifstream<char>::basic_ifstream(const std::filesystem::__cxx11::directory_entry&)’
   27 |              ifstream infile(entry);

Comment: My mistake, should be `entry.path()`

Comment: solves the errors but way to go! Thank you for the answer.